# How do I get template details when traversing an array in Meteor

Tags: javascript, css, mongodb, meteor

I have a template (X), which shows another template (Y) several times using Collection.find(). Inside template Y, I can call functions that return stuff like Y._id and Y.data. However, I need to print Y.array[], and I do so doing

```
{{#each arr}}
 <button type="submit" id="confirm" value="{{userId}}">Confirm</button>
 <button type="submit" id="confirm" value="{{userId}}">Confirm</button>
{{/each}}
```

Outside of this code, I can access Y's data just fine, but when I'm in this each loop, `this` starts referring to the current array element. How can I get the `_id` of Y for the button click (as I need both that ID and an ID inside an array of Y for the function that the buttons call)? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: `{{../_id}}` will return the ID of the parent object, which in this case would be `Y._id`

Comment: This is a valid temporary solution, however it doesn't seem very Meteory as I have to embed that in the DOM then get it out with the action handler. Using this until I figure out why Template.parentData() is not working

Answer (score 3):

@ahota is correct for accessing the parent data context from Blaze.

From your event handler in js, use `Template.parentData(1)` to access the data of the immediate parent. [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata)

Comment: it's returning null, any ideas why?

Comment: Is your event handler for X or Y? I'm assuming it's for Y.

Comment: Yep, the event handler's for Y